# "In the amazement" meaning

Tags: meaning

The sentence is :
Mulryne stared at him in the amazement.

This is from the book : The Railway Detective by Edward Marston.

What does in the amazement mean and how does it make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say it's a proofreading slip-up. The word ***the*** shouldn't be there.

It would be the same with, say, *She stared at him in [the] **excitement.*** The article is unwanted - *unless* it refers to contextually-established amazement or excitement being experienced by other people as well, but that definitely doesn't apply in the cited example.

---

Or perhaps it's an unusual dialectal usage. Or feasibly, just something that Marston thinks gives his prose an air of "regional authenticity" (it sounds like it *could* be dialectal, even Marston knows perfectly well he's making it up). But even if either of the suggestions in this paragraph are actually true, a wise learner will ignore that in favour of the first sentence in my answer!

Comment: Yes, Occam's Razor, the simplest solution is usually the best, it's a typo.

Comment: It reminds me of the Scotticism 'the noo' for 'now' or this moment (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotticism)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: Good point! It's things like that that prompted me to add my final paragraph. Not that I think it's at all likely that the text under consideration *here* is a genuine regional usage, but I wouldn't like to completely rule out the possibility of Marston making something up simply because it suited his purposes at the time. After all, he's not writing to help people learn English!

Comment: Unless the story is written in the first person (like Huckleberry Finn), I think it's unusual to use dialect in the narration.

Comment: @Barmar: I think Marston is Welsh, but there's no doubt we've had quite a few books from *Irish* writers over recent decades where the writer goes out of his way to include (revive?) quaint "dialectal regionalisms" in his text, irrespective of "first person narrative". But I might be a bit biased on that point - as a "Little Englander" myself, I tend to classify *any* "predominantly Irish" usage as dialectal. Just don't get me started on the modern tendency for all Irish people to enjoy themselves doing things *just for the **craic*** (it's ***crack**!* :)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - it's definitely not a Scotticism. I'm Scottish - a native Scots dialect speaker. Also "the noo" doesn't mean "now". It means "just now".  That doesn't mean the example isn't a regionalism, but I think it's far more likely to be a typo.  Also dialect is often used in dialogue in English books, but rarely in the actual text/narrative.

Comment: @BillyKerr I didn't mean to be disrespectful - please accept my apologies. I was just referring to what I'd heard or seen, and I didn't make the effort of actually researching it in any depth.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n You don't have to apologise.  I wasn't offended. No worries.